# Whats wrong with this jScrollpane?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jscrollpane

Does `Jscrollpane` wont work with `Asp.Net` as I am totally blank with a normal `html` page it works beautiful and when I add the same code to my `.aspx` page it shows me the normal scrollbars!

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnNxs/) which works great!

And here is the same code in my aspx page where it is not working:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
            /* Styles specific to this particular page */
            .scroll-pane
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        });
        </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div class="scroll-pane">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices
                    eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci
                    mi, in pharetra ligula. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Mauris convallis venenatis massa, quis
                    consectetur felis ornare quis. Sed aliquet nunc ac ante molestie ultricies. Nam pulvinar ultricies
                    bibendum. Vivamus diam leo, faucibus et vehicula eu, molestie sit amet dui. Proin nec orci et elit
                    semper ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
                    mus. Sed quis urna mi, ac dignissim mauris. Quisque mollis ornare mauris, sed laoreet diam malesuada
                    quis. Proin vel elementum ante. Donec hendrerit arcu ac odio tincidunt posuere. Vestibulum nec risus
                    eu lacus semper viverra.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Vestibulum dictum consectetur magna eu egestas. Praesent molestie dapibus erat, sit amet sodales
                    lectus congue ut. Nam adipiscing, tortor ac blandit egestas, lorem ligula posuere ipsum, nec
                    faucibus nisl enim eu purus. Quisque bibendum diam quis nunc eleifend at molestie libero tincidunt.
                    Quisque tincidunt sapien a sapien pellentesque consequat. Mauris adipiscing venenatis augue ut
                    tempor. Donec auctor mattis quam quis aliquam. Nullam ultrices erat in dolor pharetra bibendum.
                    Suspendisse eget odio ut libero imperdiet rhoncus. Curabitur aliquet, ipsum sit amet aliquet varius,
                    est urna ullamcorper magna, sed eleifend libero nunc non erat. Vivamus semper turpis ac turpis
                    volutpat non cursus velit aliquam. Fusce id tortor id sapien porta egestas. Nulla venenatis luctus
                    libero et suscipit. Sed sed purus risus. Donec auctor, leo nec eleifend vehicula, lacus felis
                    sollicitudin est, vitae lacinia lectus urna nec libero. Aliquam pellentesque, arcu condimentum
                    pharetra vestibulum, lectus felis malesuada felis, vel fringilla dolor dui tempus nisi. In hac
                    habitasse platea dictumst. Ut imperdiet mauris vitae eros varius eget accumsan lectus adipiscing.
                </p>
                </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone point out me the mistake I am doing as I don't believe my eyes may be you'll can find the better mistakes :)

demo.js contains:

```
$(function()
{
    // Copy the pages javascript sourcecode to the display block on the page for easy viewing...
    var sourcecodeDisplay = $('#sourcecode-display');
    if (sourcecodeDisplay.length) {
        sourcecodeDisplay.empty().append(
            $('<code />').append(
                $('<pre />').html(
                    $('#sourcecode').html().replace(/\n\t\t\t/gm, '\n').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('<', '&lt;')
                )
            )
        );
        $('#css-display').empty().append(
            $('<code />').append(
                $('<pre />').html(
                    $('#page-css').html().replace(/\n\t\t\t/gm, '\n')
                )
            )
        );
    }
});
```

This is the screenshot of my div with scrollbars:

[image]

Comment: check all your relative paths  script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js etc   Are  js files loaded correctly??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove -Yes everything works perfect for a normal html file.

Comment: I suspect the <!DOCTYPE html> declaration on top

Comment: @DotNetter what does js console say??

Comment: @DotNetter - What does `demo.js` contain?

Comment: @DrStrangeLove-It dosen't popup any error in the console.

Comment: @Aristos-After removing the doctype declaration there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load them from your website, instead of external ones, use this code:

```
<link href="/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But make sure `css` and `js` folders are in root directory of your website!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DOCTYPE` from the page. I think that is what causing the issue.

Comment: @DotNetter - What does demo.js contain? I suspect it has any js error and due to which `$(...)` is not executing which initializes the jScrollpane.

Comment: @Shankar-The demo.js and demo.css are jscrollpane website css files.

Answer (score 0):

It got working now when I changed the references this way:

```
  <link href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i told you it was your relative paths!! :))

Comment: @DrStrangeLove-But all of them worked with html file.If that was the problem it would not have worked with the plain html also.

Comment: by plain html - you mean jsfiddle??